# How to embed a file link in email using Python

Tags: python, email

I am writing a python program to send email automatically. I need to embed a file link in it.

The email body is written in Html format. 
The file link is embedded in the  tag.

Email Body (HTML)

```
...
<div>
Please remember to access the folder 
            <a href={filepath}> {filename} </a> 
to edit the form.
</div>
```

However, I can click the link but it does not show up anything.

Does anybody know how to do it? Thx a lot!

Comment: `filepath` should have quotes around it. Can you right-click-inspect the link to see if it has the correct url address?

Comment: Probably the only way to implement this transparantly for a recipient is to store the file / folder on an external resource like Dropbox.com or Google Drive and then include a shareable link to the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering your general question about how to embed a file link in an email. I am assuming you have a website. First, the file you are trying to make accessible must be in the website's document root or one of its subfolders. This is usually a directory named `public_html` or `www`. For the sake of argument, if the file is: `/home/xyxww/public_html/folder1/myfile.xyz` and the URL of the website is `http://example.com`, then with a leading `/` representing the document root (public_html, in this example), your file is at location `/folder1/myfiles.xyz`. So you need to specify the website's URL + the file location:

`<a href="http://example.com/folder1/myfile.xyz">myfile.xyz</a>`

Looking at your specific text that accompanies the link, it appears that you are expecting the recipients to be able to edit the file. If that is so, then you should include that requirement up front in your question because that puts an additional constraint on where the file can be located. In that case, as others have pointed out in comments, the file would need to be in a shareable, editable folder such as Dropbox or Google Drive provides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I do have a website. I will try the approach later. Can the file not in the subfolder of the website?

Comment: Can the file not **be** in the subfolder of the website? It can, as mentioned by @user3159253, be in a shareable folder on a Dropbox or Google Drive account just to name two possibilities and then you would copy and paste the link to that folder in your email. It would be helpful if you revised your question or added a comment here to specify what the intended purpose of all this is, in other words, what the people who receive this email will be doing with this file.